# Mysql table record settigns are not displayed in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, settings

I created a few tables in mysql. At some of them I can't see the buttons for removing/ editing etc. Here are two pictures where you can see what i mean.

this is the table where all the buttons are there:

[image]

this is the table where the buttons aren't there:

[image]

So what do i have to do for displaying these buttons?

Thank you

Comment: Couldn't see the image after edit can u update it?

Comment: Maybe the user you're logged in as doesn't have appropriate grants on the second table.

Comment: @chandran I edited it, which image can't you see?

Comment: Both images it displayed as broken jpg icon

Comment: but in phpmyadmin it says that i have all rights

Comment: check the  grant permission in mysql may be the user need a grant on these table and also try a flush privileges

Comment: lacalhost has all permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice this message near the top of your screen (just under the navigation tabs)?

[image: "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."]

Basically, phpMyAdmin is looking for a column that has a UNIQUE or PRIMARY key to make sure it's editing the proper one (if, for extreme example, you had a table with user's names and had two users named Bob Smith, phpMyAdmin isn't sure which record you want to edit. The upcoming version 4.5 actually improves this behavior a lot and makes a good effort to match even where there isn't a specific key/index specified but enough of the other columns are different to piece together a safe SQL query.

So to see the columns for your table, you can either wait for version 4.5 (or run a development snapshot), or add a UNIQUE or PRIMARY index on a column. In one case I've actually added an new column to be the AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY key, done some editing, then dropped the column again.